# Binary Search Tree Recursive Remove

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

My program keeps breaking when I try to find the max of my remove function. What I'm trying to do is overwrite what the user wants to remove with the maximum of the left tree, then delete that node instead. It keeps breaking once it reaches the first Else. The recursion is breaking my mind. Where's my flaw?

This is the remove function with its private recursive sibling.

```
template<typename TYPE>
bool BinarySearchTree<TYPE>::remove(TYPE& data)
{
    bool found = search(dataOut);
    if(found)
        TRoot = Premove(TRoot, data);
    return found;
}

template<typename TYPE>
Node<TYPE>* BinarySearchTree<TYPE>::Premove(Node<TYPE>* root, TYPE& data)
{
    Node<TYPE>* del;
    Node<TYPE>* max;
    if(root)
    {
        if(root->data > data)
            root->left = Premove(root->left, data);
        else if(root->data < data)
            root->right = Premove(root->right, data);
        else
        {
            if(root->left && root->right)
            {
                max = root->left;
                while(max->data < max->right->data)
                    max = max->right;
                root->data = max->data;
                max = Premove(root, max->data);

            }
            else
            {
                del = root;
                root = (root->right) ? root->right : root->left;
                delete pDel;
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what "breaking" means?  (Regarding the code, not your mind)

Comment: Well it seems to fine get through the while but then when I try to remove `max` it just goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most probably here:
`while(max->data < max->right->data) max = max->right;`

You are running out of the tree (`max->right` will become NULL eventually).
Actually, as it's a binary search tree, there is no need to compare `data`. It's enough just to walk to the right while it's possible: `while (max->right) max=max->right;`

Also note the last assignment in this branch: there are two additional problems. First of all, instead of `max = Premove(...)` you should do `root->left = Premove(...)` (otherwise you will not modify the root->left reference). Second, you should call `Premove` for `root->left` and not for `root`: `root->left = Premove(root->left, max->data);` (otherwise you just get an infinite recursion).

Answer (score 0):

I think your while statement should be like this:

```
while(max && max->right && max->data < max->right->data )
```

In some cases in your code, `max` or `max->right` could be `NULL` and it cause run_time error.